# Kohana 3 Check if ajax request

Tags: ajax, kohana-3

I'm currently using this to check if the request is an ajax request:

```
if ( ! Request::$is_ajax || Request::instance() == $this->request)
{
    exit;
}
```

If I try to access the page directly it'll exit, but if I make an ajax request, it'll also exit. I also tried just:

```
if ( ! Request::$is_ajax)
{
    exit;
}
```

And vice versa, but the script still exits everytime. If I remove the check, the ajax works as normal. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you are using Ajax,
   `Request::instance() ===
   $this->request` is TRUE. Use this
   condition for HMVC calls.
2. Kohana marks request as Ajax when
   `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
   == 'xmlhttprequest'` condition is TRUE. Check your client headers
   (with firebug for example), maybe
   your JS doesnt send this header. Or,
   may be you are using flash uploader?

Comment: Yea using firebug X-Requested-With was set with XMLHttpRequest. Not using flash uploader, it's a simple autocomplete input textbox that fetches the results in JSON. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Well that is weird, I was trying it again and somehow it works now using if ( ! Request::$is_ajax) {     exit; } Maybe my browser somehow cached something, no idea.

Comment: with the current version, this check can be done with `Request::current()->is_ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

`Request::current()->is_ajax()` this code works for me.